# Can this volatile access be optimized out?

Tags: c, optimization, language-lawyer, volatile

From *ISO/IEC 9899:201x* section *5.1.2.3 Program execution:*

> 2 **Accessing a volatile object**, modifying an object, modifying a file,
> or calling a function that does any of those operations **are** all **side
> effects**, which are changes in the state of the execution
> environment. Evaluation of an expression in general includes both
> value computations and initiation of side effects. Value computation
> for an lvalue expression includes determining the identity of the
> designated object.

So, accessing (read\write) a volatile is called a side effect.
Lets continue:

> 4 In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified
> by the semantics. **An actual implementation need not evaluate part of
> an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no
> needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a
> function or accessing a volatile object)**.

So if I read a volatile (which is a side effect) but doing nothing with the fetched value I read, this access is actually not needed and can be optimized out.

OK, also:

> 6 The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> - **Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the
>   rules of the abstract machine**.
> - At program termination, all data
>   written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of
>   the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
> - The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place
>   as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that
>   unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to
>   ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program
>   waiting for input. This is the observable behavior of the program.

So, to my understanding, section *4* is a rule of the abstract machine, and section *6* says that volatiles needs to be evaluated strictly according to the abstract machine rules (which section *4* is). So the read access (without further using the fetched value) can be optimized out.

So, take a look at this code:

```
volatile int *timer_reg = REGISTER_ADDRESS_CONST;
while (*timer_reg  == 0) {/*empty loop*/}
```

This code, blocks the execution until the HW raises a bit at the address pointed by `timer_reg`. This register acts as a kind of timer which was configured to raise a bit after certain time period elapsed. When the timer elapses the busy wait ends and execution continues.

Now, can this `while` loop be optimized out? I have tried this with many compilers online with different optimization levels, and it seems that it does not.
Is there something I'm missing here? to my understanding, standard says explicitly it can be optimized.

**EDIT:** My point is that because of the fact that the while loop is empty, maybe the compiler can consider the fetched volatile value as unneeded .

Comment: You _are_ using the fetched value.

Comment: @Mat I've edited the question

Comment: The body of the `while` loop is empty, but the loop as a whole is not.

Comment: Observable behavior cannot be optimized out, and access to objects of volatile-qualified types is part of the observable behavior (although what constitutes access to an object of volatile-qualified type is implementation defined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So if I read a volatile (which is a side effect) without using the value I read, this access is actually not needed and can be optimized out.

No. The text says *"its value is not used **and** that no needed side effects are produced"*. It does not say "**or**". Regardless if you are using the value, there is a side effect present - an access to a volatile variable.

> So the read access (without further using the fetched value) can be optimized out.

No.

> Now, can this while loop be optimized out?

No. The data pointed at is volatile-qualified. At each lap in the loop it must read `*timer_reg` directly from memory. It may not optimize away the read. It may not re-order it. It may not cache it/pre-fetch it.

Comment: AFAIK, the C standard has nothing to say about caching for volatile objects.

Comment: @IanAbbott Obviously it says nothing about memories or hardware at all, but if the CPU would cache volatile objects, everything would break. The C standard just says "Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine" which can be interpreted as no re-ordering of any kind allowed. Pre-fetch caching is a form of re-ordering, where values are read in advance. It is then arguably the compiler's job to ensure this doesn't happen. Or if it is beyond the compiler to do that, the hardware might not be suitable for running C programs.

Comment: Presumably, my PC with its GCC C compiler is unsuitable for running C programs.

Comment: @IanAbbott If it performs caching of volatile-qualified variables, then indeed. The problem here is to make the C committee/gcc people/PC programmers understand how important volatile is in hardware-related programming. If I point at a memory-mapped I/O register, it can't run off to store that register value in cache.

Comment: Memory-mapped I/O registers are generally mapped to non-cached regions, but that has nothing to do with the compiler. More relevant is the use of volatile-qualified objects in multi-processor systems. A PC has cache coherency between the processors, so writes to cacheable memory by one processor will eventually be seen when read by the other processors, although they will not necessarily be seen in the same order as they are written unless the compiler gives "acquire semantics" to volatile reads. (I understand that Microsoft C compilers do that by default except on ARM processors.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Compiler vendors try to put the burden of using memory barriers on the programmers. But if you read the standard strictly, then volatile access must act as a memory barrier, since "In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics". The C standard concept of sequenced before/after applies to all manner of multi-processing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191170/discussion-between-ian-abbott-and-lundin).

Comment: is it true to say that the bold text in section 4 is not abstract machine rule (as it is talking about optimization) therefore have nothing to do with the requirement that volatiles should be evaluated strictly according to abstract machine rules?

Comment: also, so what is the possible volatile optimization the standard says is allowed in the bold text in section 4 then?